# Dynamic values in Help Text Django

Tags: python, django

Given the following code:

```
body = models.TextField(max_length=500, help_text=_("Maks. 500 tegn"))
```

Is it possible to make the `max_length` value appear inside the help text string?

```
help_text=_("Maks. %(max_length)s tegn")
```

Comment: Do you use a form for the help text to show up?

Comment: @ShangWang I use {{ form.help_text }} and display it in plain html text.

Comment: Use a variable for the max_length value like `max_value=500` , then use that variable in the `max_length=max_value` and use the same variable in the help text too

Comment: @kushtrimh that's a good idea. I will implement that. :)